# (Physics engine for games like Sugar, Sugar) SpriteKit performance optimization for many physics sprites

Tags: swift, performance, sprite-kit, game-physics, physics-engine

I'm a iOS game developer and I saw an interesting physics & draw game "Sugar, Sugar" recently. In the game, there are lots of pixel particles (thousands of them) generated from the screen and free falling to the ground. Player can draw any shape of lines, which can guide those particles to certain cups. A image from google:
[image]

I'm trying to achieve similar effect using SpriteKit with Swift. Here's what I got:
[image]

Then I encounter a performance problem. Once the number of particles > 100. The CPU and energy costs are very high. (I use iPhone 6s). So I believe the Physics Engine in "Sugar, Sugar" is much simpler than the realistic SpriteKit. But I don't know what's the physics engine there and how can I achieve this in SpriteKit?

PS:
I use one single image as texture for all those particles, only loaded once to save performance. I only use SKSpriteNode, no ShapeNode is used for performance reason too.

Comment: No physics engine needed. The game sugar uses little square pixels, with very simple rules (is pixel below me empty move down, is pixel to the left of me move right...etc) it s pure (n) problem.  You are using complex spheres with a full physics engine that must compare each against each and is a (n*n) problem. Don't use the physics engine just keep an array of pixel locations, directions, and test neighbours for movement.

Comment: @Blindman67 How do you realize the bouncing effect caused by the increased speed (gravity) without a physic engine? Little points of sugar aren't stones..

Comment: Easy. If `y` is the position and `dy` is the delta y then apply gravity with `dy += grav`. This is a simple acceleration and is exactly the same as applying F=G * (M1*M2) / (r*r) (newtons grav equation). For the bounce check the pixel below if occupied bounce (negate and reduce dy) else add the `dy` to the `y` pos eg `if(pixel(x,y+1) == occupied ){ dy = -dy * bounceLoss; } else { y += dy }`

Comment: @Blindman67 I know you can recalculate all dynamic situation as physic do it , but at what price? Really, seems to re-make retro games in Basic (and I like it :) ) but this situation exist only because SKShapeNode is a piece of crap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not done a sand sim for a long time so I thought I would create a quick demo for you.

It is done in javascript, left mouse adds sand, right mouse draws lines. Depending on the machine it will handle thousands of grains of sand.

It works by creating an array of pixels, each pixel has a x,y position a delta x,y and a flag to indicate it is inactive (dead). Every frame I clear the display and then add the walls. Then for each pixel I check if there are pixels to the sides or below (depending on the direction of movement) and add sideways slippage, bounce of wall, or gravity. If a pixel has not moved for some time I set it as dead and only draw it to save time on the calculations.

The sim is very simple, the first pixel (grain) will never bump into another because it is drawn with a clear display, pixels can only see pixels created before them. But this works well as they self organize and will not overlap each other.

You can find the logic in the function display, (second function from bottom) there is some code for auto demo, then code for drawing the walls, displaying the walls, getting the pixel data and then doing the sim for each pixel.

Its not perfect (like the game you have mentioned) but it is just a quick hack to show how it is done. Also I made it to big for the inset window so best viewed full page.

```js
/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js begin **/
const CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID = "canv";
const U = undefined;
var w, h, cw, ch; // short cut vars 
var canvas, ctx, mouse;
var globalTime = 0; 
var createCanvas, resizeCanvas, setGlobals;
var L = typeof log === "function" ? log : function(d){ console.log(d); }
createCanvas = function () {
    var c,cs;
    cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; 
    c.id = CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID;    
    cs.position = "absolute";
    cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
    cs.width = cs.height = "100%";
    cs.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.appendChild(c); 
    return c;
}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === U) { canvas = createCanvas(); }
    canvas.width = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/4);
    canvas.height = Math.floor(window.innerHeight/4); 
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals(); }
}
setGlobals = function(){ cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2; ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2; }
mouse = (function(){
    function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
    var mouse = {
        x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, buttonRaw : 0,
        over : false,  // mouse is over the element
        bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
        mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
    };
    var m = mouse;
    function mouseMove(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        m.x = e.offsetX; m.y = e.offsetY;
        if (m.x === U) { m.x = e.clientX; m.y = e.clientY; }
        m.alt = e.altKey; m.shift = e.shiftKey; m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
        if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1]; }  
        else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2]; }
        else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false; }
        else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true; }
        else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta; }
        else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail; }
        if (m.callbacks) { m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e)); }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    m.addCallback = function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            if (m.callbacks === U) { m.callbacks = [callback]; }
            else { m.callbacks.push(callback); }
        } else { throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function"); }
    }
    m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
        if (m.element !== U) { m.removeMouse(); }        
        m.element = element === U ? document : element;
        m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === U ? false : blockContextMenu;
        m.mouseEvents.forEach( n => { m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
        if (m.blockContextMenu === true) { m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false); }
    }
    m.remove = function () {
        if (m.element !== U) {
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => { m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
            if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) { m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);}
            m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = U;
        }
    }
    return mouse;
})();
var done = function(){
    window.removeEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas)
    mouse.remove();
    document.body.removeChild(canvas);    
    canvas = ctx = mouse = U;
    L("All done!")
}

resizeCanvas(); // create and size canvas
mouse.start(canvas,true); // start mouse on canvas and block context menu
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); // add resize event
var simW = 200;
var simH = 200;
var wallCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
wallCanvas.width = simW;
wallCanvas.height = simH;
var wallCtx = wallCanvas.getContext("2d"); 
var bounceDecay = 0.7;
var grav = 0.5;
var slip = 0.5;
var sandPerFrame = 5;
var idleTime  = 50;
var pixels = [];
var inactiveCounter = 0;
var demoStarted;
var lastMouse;
var wallX;
var wallY;
function display(){  // Sim code is in this function
    var blocked;
    var obstructed;
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;
    var startX = Math.floor(w / 2) - Math.floor(simW / 2);
    var startY = Math.floor(h / 2) - Math.floor(simH / 2);    
    if(lastMouse === undefined){
        lastMouse = mouse.x + mouse.y;
    }
    if(lastMouse === mouse.x + mouse.y){
        inactiveCounter += 1;
        
    }else{
        inactiveCounter = 0;
    }
    if(inactiveCounter > 10 * 60){
        if(demoStarted === undefined){
            wallCtx.beginPath();
            var sy = simH / 6;
            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
                wallCtx.moveTo(simW * (1/6) - 10,sy * i + sy * 1);
                wallCtx.lineTo(simW * (3/ 6) - 10,sy * i + sy  * 2);
                wallCtx.moveTo(simW * (5/6) + 10,sy * i + sy  * 0.5);
                wallCtx.lineTo(simW * (3/6) +10,sy * i + sy  * 1.5);
            }
            wallCtx.stroke();            
          
            
        }
        mouse.x = startX * 4 + (simW * 2);
        mouse.y = startY * 4  +  (simH * 2 )/5;
        lastMouse = mouse.x + mouse.y;
        mouse.buttonRaw = 1;
        
    }

    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.strokeRect(startX+1,startY+1,simW-2,simH-2)
    ctx.drawImage(wallCanvas,startX,startY); // draws the walls


    if(mouse.buttonRaw & 4){  // if right button draw walls
        if(mouse.x/4 > startX && mouse.x/4 < startX + simW && mouse.y/4 > startY && mouse.y/4 < startY + simH){
            if(wallX === undefined){
                wallX = mouse.x/4 - startX
                wallY = mouse.y/4 - startY
            }else{
                wallCtx.beginPath();
                wallCtx.moveTo(wallX,wallY);
                wallX = mouse.x/4 - startX
                wallY = mouse.y/4 - startY
                wallCtx.lineTo(wallX,wallY);
                wallCtx.stroke();
            }
        }
        
        
    }else{
        wallX = undefined;
    }
    if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1){ // if left button add sand
        for(var i = 0; i < sandPerFrame; i ++){
            var dir = Math.random() * Math.PI;
            var speed = Math.random() * 2;
            var dx = Math.cos(dir) * 2;
            var dy = Math.sin(dir) * 2;
            pixels.push({
                x : (Math.floor(mouse.x/4) - startX) + dx,
                y : (Math.floor(mouse.y/4) - startY) + dy,
                dy : dx * speed,
                dx : dy * speed,
                dead : false,
                inactive : 0,
                r : Math.floor((Math.sin(globalTime / 1000) + 1) * 127),
                g : Math.floor((Math.sin(globalTime / 5000) + 1) * 127),
                b : Math.floor((Math.sin(globalTime / 15000) + 1) * 127),
            });
        }
        if(pixels.length > 10000){ // if over 10000 pixels reset
            pixels = [];
        }
   
    }
    // get the canvas pixel data
    var data = ctx.getImageData(startX, startY,simW,simH);
    var d = data.data;
    
    // handle each pixel;
    for(var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 1){
        var p = pixels[i];
        if(!p.dead){
            var ind = Math.floor(p.x) * 4 + Math.floor(p.y) * 4 * simW;
            d[ind + 3] = 0;
            obstructed = false;
            p.dy += grav;
            var dist = Math.floor(p.y + p.dy) - Math.floor(p.y);
            if(Math.floor(p.y + p.dy) - Math.floor(p.y) >= 1){
                if(dist >= 1){
                    bocked = d[ind + simW * 4 + 3];
                }
                if(dist >= 2){
                    bocked += d[ind + simW * 4 * 2 + 3];
                }
                if(dist >= 3){
                    bocked += d[ind + simW * 4 * 3 + 3];
                }
                if(dist >= 4){
                    bocked += d[ind + simW * 4 * 4 + 3];
                }
                
                if( bocked > 0 || p.y + 1 > simH){
                    p.dy = - p.dy * bounceDecay;
                    obstructed = true;
                }else{
                    p.y += p.dy;
                }
            }else{
                p.y += p.dy;
            }
            if(d[ind + simW * 4 + 3] > 0){
                if(d[ind + simW * 4 - 1] === 0 && d[ind + simW * 4 + 4 + 3] === 0 ){
                    p.dx += Math.random() < 0.5 ? -slip/2 : slip/2;
                }else
                if(d[ind + 4 + 3] > 0  && d[ind + simW * 4 - 1] === 0 ){
                    p.dx -= slip;
                    
                }else
                if(d[ind - 1] + d[ind - 1 - 4] > 0  ){
                    p.dx += slip/2;
                    
                }else
                if(d[ind +3] + d[ind + 3 + 4] > 0  ){
                    p.dx -= slip/2;
                    
                }else
                if(d[ind + 1] + d[ind + 1] > 0 && d[ind + simW * 4 + 3] > 0 && d[ind + simW * 4 + 4 + 3] === 0 ){
                    p.dx += slip;
                    
                }else
                if(d[ind + simW * 4 - 1] === 0 ){
                    p.dx +=  -slip/2;
                    
                    
                }else
                if(d[ind + simW * 4 + 4 + 3] === 0 ){
                    p.dx +=  -slip/2;
                }
            }
            if(p.dx < 0){
                if(Math.floor(p.x + p.dx) - Math.floor(p.x) <= -1){
                    if(d[ind - 1] > 0){
                        p.dx = -p.dx * bounceDecay;
                    }else{
                        p.x += p.dx;
                    }
                }else{
                    p.x += p.dx;
                }
            }else
            if(p.dx > 0){
                if(Math.floor(p.x + p.dx) - Math.floor(p.x) >= 1){
                    if(d[ind + 4 + 3] > 0){
                        p.dx = -p.dx * bounceDecay;
                    }else{
                        p.x += p.dx;
                    }
                }else{
                    p.x += p.dx;
                }
                
            }
            var ind = Math.floor(p.x) * 4 + Math.floor(p.y) * 4 * simW;
            d[ind ] = p.r;
            d[ind + 1] = p.g;
            d[ind + 2] = p.b;
            d[ind + 3] = 255;
            if(obstructed && p.dx * p.dx + p.dy * p.dy < 1){
                p.inactive += 1;
                if(p.inactive > idleTime){
                    p.dead = true;
                }
            }
        }else{
            var ind = Math.floor(p.x) * 4 + Math.floor(p.y) * 4 * simW;
            d[ind ] = p.r;
            d[ind + 1] = p.g;
            d[ind + 2] = p.b;
            d[ind + 3] = 255;

        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(data,startX, startY);
    
    
}
function update(timer){ // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display();  // call demo code
    // continue until mouse right down
    if (!(mouse.buttonRaw & 2)) { requestAnimationFrame(update); } else { done(); }
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);

/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```

```css
* { font-family: arial; }
canvas { image-rendering: pixelated; }
```

```html
<p>Right click drag to draw walls</p>
<p>Left click hold to drop sand</p>
<p>Demo auto starts in 10 seconds is no input</p>
<p>Sim resets when sand count reaches 10,000 grains</p>
<p>Middle button quits sim</p>
```

Comment: OMG! Awesome answer! I was expecting a answer like your comments below my post, I never expected you write complete code that can run. It surely does what I asked. It also has bouncing etc effects. I'm not familiar with JS or pixel coding, but I see the logic. I'll keep this as a reference and come back frequently to check my code. Anyway thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: BTW: for anyone is trying to running this code, Safari may not works due to the JS, I guess. Use another browser like Chrome.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis Does not run on Safari. I will have to have a look at that ans see what can be done.. Thanks for the heads up, I don't have Safari on my home machine. It was a bit of a rush job so it is not that well commented but most of it is about reading the pixels from the buffer, I concentrate on the alpha channel that is the 4th byte `d[ind + 3]` if zero then it is empty else it is occupied.

Comment: I guess it's Safari's own problem, but the code runs great in Chrome. Right, I'm not familiar with pixel coding, so the 1st time I saw someData[3], I thought what's that?! then I found out that's the alpha channel. That's interesting cause I didn't realize how to check the pixel is empty or not before this code. I looked up Swift in iOS, I believe it has similar method to check pixels. I guess I can even check pixels on a certain view in views hierarchy in iOS so that I can add a background view with the same implementation.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis Even if you can not access the pixel data directly all you have to do is create an array to hold the locations of obstructions and sand. And if you are short on memory use a bit array (array of 32 bit ints, with each int representing 32 pixels). This is a very old school technique from way back when 8Bit PCs where high tech, and 4K RAM was all you could ever want....

Comment: Hi, I just implemented similar method in iOS. It works somehow, but not as good as yours. some sands just stuck/stick to a slope line. So I went through your code several times. I have questions: (1) there seems to be many cases when calculating dx, I guess you check the pixels including left, right, leftDown, rightDown directions, but I'm not sure why you are check the condition like "d[ind+3] + d[ind+3+4]>0", why need make the addition of two pixels? So could you clear that part for me? why there are so many different cases to calculate dx.

Comment: another question(2): when calculating dy, you have dist, and you check it for dist>1,2,3,4. I guess you just check as far as 4 pixels below the pixel, but why 4? not 5, 6. and why not just check 1? Is it because the dy could be larger than 1 and you believe it's not larger than 4, then only check 1~4 is safe here?

Comment: Last quesiton(3): when this JS code running, what's the time interval or FPS to call the update function? like 60FPS?

Comment: @ValarMorghulis 60fps is the max rate but it will depend on the device and will drop to 30fps, then 20fps if the load is to much. Adding two pixels is the same as checking if each is set `0 + 0 === 0` so both empty, `1 + 0 > 0`, I check 4 down is just an arbitrary  distance. Much more than 4 will not do much to improve the sim, and only add to the load. Many tests for dx is to ensure good sideways movement. Though I did not put that much thought into it. You could have the walls have slightly diff colours that would indicate a push direction on the sand making for better slippage